# How to write division & remainder code without mult or div instructions in MIPS?

Tags: mips

I've got to take 2 user inputs and find the product, quotient and remainder. I cant use the multipication or division operators either.

I've got the multiplication code:

```
L1:
add  $t2,$s1,$s0  #diving $s0 by $s1
bge  $s1, $s0, EXIT   # branch if ! ( i < k )
addi $s1, $s1, 1      # k++
add  $t2, $s1, $s0    # i = i * 2 
EXIT:
```

How would I find the quotient and remainder? I tried just changing all the `add`s to `sub`s but no luck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MIPS Calculator implementing division with substraction and addition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22155719/mips-calculator-implementing-division-with-substraction-and-addition)

Answer (score 5):

use the following commands to get the quotient and the remainder

```
rem   d, s1, s2     #d = s1 % s2;  gives remainder
```

Answer (score 3):

If you used addition with a loop to multiply two numbers, then use subtraction with a loop to divide them. Some psuedocode:

```
main:
    #initialize registers

loop:
    #dividend -= divsor
    #quotient++

    #temp = dividend - divsor
    #if temp < 0 jump to done
    #jump to loop

done:
    #remainder = temp
```

Comment: you know how to do this in MIPS?

Comment: Yes. Have you tried implementing a new solution with the pseudo-code I gave you? It's literally translatable line-for-line.