# MIPS Calculator implementing division with subtraction and addition, avoiding DIV and REM instructions

Tags: assembly, mips, integer-division

I'm working on the classic MIPS calculator example, but am attempting to change the divis (division) routine below to use only addition and subtraction instead of MIPS div operation (similar to what I have done with multiplication). This is probably very easy to do, but I am new to MIPS and every attempt I have made so far hasn't worked. Help?

I'm using qtspim as my simulator

What I have so far for division:

```
    start_divis:    
        add $t1, $zero, $s0   #make copy of first integer value in $s0
        add $t2, $zero, $s1   #make copy of second integer value in $s1
        add $t0, $zero, $zero #make $t0 the temporary variable to act as a counter

    div_loop:
        slt $t3, $t2, $t1        #checks if $t1 > $t2
        sub $t1, $t1, $t2        #subtract $t2 from $t1
        addi $t0, 1              #add one to counter
        bne $t3, $zero, div_loop #if first number < second number, loop

    end_divis:
        move $s5, $t0      #store answer  
        move $s6, $t1      #store remainder
        la  $a0, divi_s    #get division symbol
        move $s7, $a0      #move it to $s7

        j div_ans          #jump to div_ans
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can get away with integer division (i.e. `1/2 = 0`) consider the following pseudo code:

```
function multiply(a, b):

    sum := 0
    for i = 0 to b:
        sum := sum + a

    return sum

function divide(a,b):

    count := 0

    while a ≥ b:
        a := a - b
        count := count + 1

    return count
```

---

There are a few errors with what you've written:

Firstly the line

`slt $t3, $t2, $t1        #checks if $t1 > $t2`

is incorrect. The correct way to negate > is with ≤. This means the line should be changed to:

`sle $t3, $t2, $t1        #checks if $t1 > $t2`

Next you have the condition of your loop at the top but the actual branch that uses it at the bottom. You should be aware that a while loop always checks the condition at the top.

Consider:

```
div_loop:
    sle $t3, $t2, $t1        #checks if $t1 > $t2
    beq $t3, $zero, end_divis #if first number < second number, break

    sub $t1, $t1, $t2        #subtract $t2 from $t1
    addi $t0, 1              #add one to counter
    j div_loop               #loop
```

Comment: thank you for your response, I am aware of the general algorithm to use, but what I am having trouble with is translating them to MIPS since it is my first time using the language

Comment: can you ellaborate on what you are having trouble with in regards to implementation? If you are having trouble with loops perhaps it would be best to consult an appropriate tutorial-ish resource.

Comment: Sure, see edit for what I have so far for division (I managed to get multiplication working) using a method similar to yours above. It currently doesn't work for remainders, not sure why.

Comment: when your above pseudo-code is complete, a should be the remainder correct?

Comment: Ya, I didn't think about that but I suppose `a` would be the remainder.